# Encrypt Credentials, Export, then Import

Tags: powershell, password-encryption

I've been working with Powershell for quite some time now but I don't understand how the encryption works, not even sure I'm using the right syntax from reading the help files.

```
#Get User Information
$User = Read-Host "Please enter your username"
$Password = Read-Host "Please enter your password. This will be encrypted" -AsSecureString | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#Define a Key File
$KeyFile = "C:\Powershell\AES.key"
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | out-file $KeyFile

#Encrypt using AES
$PasswordFile = "C:\Powershell\Password.txt"
$KeyFile = "C:\Powershell\AES.key"
$Key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File $PasswordFile

#Set credentials to be called.
$myCredentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)

#Open text file.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -Credential $MyCredentials -ScriptBlock{
    Invoke-Item C:\Powershell\Password.txt
    }
```

I received an error when running this and I'm not sure why I can't pipe this:

> ConvertFrom-SecureString : The input object cannot be bound to any
>   parameters for the command either because the command does not take
>   pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the
>   parameters that take  pipeline input. At C:\Powershell\Password.ps1:15
>   char:13
>   + **$Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $Key | Out-File $PasswordFile**
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.Security.SecureString:String) [ConvertFrom-SecureString],
>   ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromSecureStringCommand

Are there any encryption experts that can help? I'm trying to simply save a password to a text file (encrypted) and then I want to use another script to call various programs using new credentials using the encrypted password, but I can't even get the encrypted password to work correctly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things simple:

**To Save the Credential Object to disk:**

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$Key = [byte]1..32
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -Key $Key | Set-Content c:\cred.key
```

**To Load it back to Powershell:**

```
$Key = [byte]1..32
$username = "type the username here"
$encrypted = Get-Content c:\cred.key | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $Key

## Create The Credential Object:

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $encrypted)
```

Sure that this is not secured, because everyone who see your code can re-use the credential,

If you are not using a key at all, the credential will be encrypted with your current user, and only the current user can decrypt it back.

Comment: That seems to work just fine. I'm trying to pass these credentials off in the Invoke-Command though and everytime I run that to call a txt file I get nothing. Perhaps I'm not doing that part correctly. Nvm, I'm incredibly dumb and over thinking things, it's Monday. Thank you!