# Need to connect to remote server and execute ps1 script using jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, powershell-remoting

I created a Jenkins job that needs to connect to a remote machine and execute a ps1 script.

```
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String "4444"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "eeeee\eee",$pw
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName server1 -Credential $cred
Enter-PSSession $sess
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989524/encrypt-credentials-export-then-import/35990001#35990001

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be better served with Invoke-Command than Enter-PSSession.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

Something along the lines of:

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $creds -ComputerName $server -FilePath $scriptname -ArgumentList $arg1, $arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the remote machine as a slave, then run your script from 'execute windows Batch command' or install Powershell plugin and 'Run powershell script'.

**Links:**

1. Add windows slave: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows
2. Powershell plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin

Comment: After following your steps when i run build in jenkins i see below error.
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
    + PSComputerName        : 002
Zip file extraction is completed
Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\PHESBBATECT002\d$\Packages\ 
   RTO:String) [Test-Path], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.Powe 
   rShell.Commands.TestPathCommand+ PSComputerName

Comment: $ServerName = @("***002","***003")
    foreach($Server in $ServerName)
{
$RTODest = "\\$Server\d$\Packages\RTO"
if(!(test-path $RTODest))
     {
$file = "\\***001\e$\Packages\RTO.zip"
new-item -path "\\$Server\d$\" -name "Packages" -type directory
 $destination = "\\$Server\d$\Packages"
     $shell = new-object -com shell.application
     $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
     foreach($item in $zip.items())
     {
     $shell.NameSpace($destination).copyhere($item)
     }
        Write-Host "Zip file extraction is completed"
     }
     else
{Write-Host "RTO Folder already exit" 
}
}
}
UNZIP-File

Answer (score 0):

As mention above enter-session should not be used in a non interactive mode.  ALSO note that the Jenkins Service needs to be running as Network Services or a Named users.  If it is running as "local service" it will not be able to create outbound network connections.  It will hang at new-pssession